# Specifying default arguments for a Console Based Program

Tags: windows-xp, console

If I create a shortcut for a Console based application (which has not been compiled by me) or pin it to the start menu, is there any way I can specify certain default (for me) command line arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

First, create a shortcut to the executable console application by copying the executable, right click in the destination folder (where you want the shortcut to be) and selecting "Paste shortcut".

Now, right click the shortcut and select "Properties". Now, all you need to do is to add the arguments to the end of the path, so the full path is like this:

```
"C:/Program Files/Foo/bar.exe" -v 23 --limit=xbox
```

Or however else your program accepts arguments.

From here, you can now pin it to the start menu or whatever

Here's a screenshot showing arguments used for Chrome:

[image]

Comment: If someone could make (or find) a screenshot for this, it would be appreciated so much. I only use OS X, so it is a bit hard to screenshot Windows.

Comment: This does work with a shortcut, but it doesn't with a program pinned to the Start Menu. Is there any way for this to work for the pinned program too?

Comment: Added a screenshot for you, joshhunt.

Comment: I think I can't pin a program to the Start menu and then specify arguments, but I must first create a shortcut specifying arguments and then pin that shortcut to the Start Menu. I think that's the way to go.

Comment: correct, you can't add switches to pinned porgrams, create the shortcut, add the switches and then pin the shortcut.